# Uploading enormous amount of data to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have to upload about 16 million records to a MySQL 5.1 server on a shared webspace which does not permit LOAD DATA functionality. The table is an Innodb table. I have not assigned any keys yet.

Therefore, I use a Python script to convert my CSV file (of 2.5 GB of size) to an SQL file with individual INSERT statements. I've launched the SQL file, and the process is incredibly slow, it feels like 1000-1500 lines are processed every minute!

In the meantime, I read about bulk inserts, but did not find any reliable source telling how many records one insert statement can have. Do you know?

Is it an advantage to have no keys and add them later?

Would a transaction around all the insert help speed up the process? In fact, there's just a single connection (mine) working with the database at this time.

Comment: The transaction would just make it slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `insert ... values ...` syntax to insert multiple rows running a single request your query size is limited by [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value rather than by number of rows.

Concerning keys: it's a good practice to define keys before any data manipulations. Actually, when you build a model you *must* think of keys, relations, indexes etc.

It's better do define indexes before you insert data as well. `CREATE INDEX` works quite slowly on huge datasets. But postponing indexes creation is not a huge disadvantage.

To make your inserts faster try to turn [autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) mode on and do not run concurrent requests on your tables.

Comment: max_allowed_packet size happens to be 16,777,216, so given that one INSERT line is about 300 bytes of text, that would mean about 50,000 records per insert execution.

Comment: Also, autocommit is ON by default on my server.

Comment: I changed my script to have it produce bulk inserts with 10,000 records at a time and this was indeed the solution! From running around a week with single inserts, the execution time now dropped to about 6 hours. Good stuff!